# How to convert table based layout with Bootstrap "row" and "col-*-*"

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I am working on site which is based on table-layout (no div). Now requirement change and has to re-create so that it look responsive, and for responsive we choose bootstrap as option.

Now, How can I convert tables layout into bootstrap grid layout so can 1. look not change, 2. have responsive also.

table-layout is too complex in site. lots of nesting is there. For example:

```
<table border="0" width='100%' bgcolor='#ff00ff'>
<tr style='padding-bottom:1em;'>
<td>
    <table border="0">
        <tr valign='bottom'>
            <td width='50'>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <img border="0" src="#" width="100" height="300">
            </td>
            <td width='25'>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <span style='font-size:10px;color:#cccccc;'>Alpha testing</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
<td align='right'>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td align='center' colspan='3'>
                <span>Another tesing text</span>
                <span style='color:#FFFFCC;'> - </span>
                <span style='font-size:11px;color:#fffff;'>Random text</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
```

For example how can I convert above code with bootstrap `row`, `col-*-*` grid-layout.

Trust me, I tried a lot to convert this, but sometime looks change or some time just not work at all.

General suggestion on how to convert table base layout into bootstrap are also welcome.

Comment: you can nest rows and columns in bootstrap just like tables to <tr> becomes a .row and <td> becomes .col-*-*. The bootstrap column grid is 12 columns so you have to do a little math.

Answer (score 39):

Here is some great literature: [Bootstrap 3 Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid)

- Replace table and tbody with `div class="container"`
- Replace tr with `div class="row"`
- Replace td with `div class="col-ww-nn"`

  - Where `ww` is device width (`xs`, `sm`, `md`, `lg`)
  - Where `nn` is a number 1-12 for width percentage (divided by 12)

Below is your updated code (including some syntax fixes too).  Note, I've added responsiveness so that on phones (`xs` devices) your second main column would be a separate line.  And you can make images responsive with `img-response` so that it's size changes with the device.

```
<div class="container" style="background-color:#ff00ff">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
                    <img src="#" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
                    <span style="font-size:10px;color:#cccccc;">Alpha testing</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
                    <span>Another tesing text</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
                    <span style="color:#ffffcc;"> - </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
                    <span style="font-size:11px;color:#ffffff;">Random text</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, but one question -  While reading docs on Bootstrap I also found that container or container-fluid is not nestable. So, It is ok, to nest as you did in code?

Comment: Good find.  You can get away with it but for proper bootstrap usage, you should not nest containers as it may cause unwanted behaviors.  I have updated my code accordingly by simply removing the inner containers.  I guess we are learning together.

Comment: What if I have more than 12 columns in my table?

Comment: @danielrvt Bootstrap container rows and columns are meant to be used for responsive page layout to replace the old method of using tables.  Tables should still be used for actual data tables.  If you need more than 12 columns in a row, you would need to override the Bootstrap defaults to update percentages accordingly.  Note, you would also need to override column offsets, push, and pull.

Answer (score 6):

Actually it is not so complex.

Just skip every `<table>` and `<tbody>` tag, treat every `<tr>` as block element with `class="row"` and every `<td>` as block element with `class="col-*-*"`. Nesting Bootstrap grid is totally okey, so if you have somthing like that:

```
<tr style='padding-bottom:1em;'>
  <td>
    <table border="0">
        <tr valign='bottom'>
            <td width='50'>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <img border="0" src="#" width="100" height="300">
            </td>
            <td width='25'>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <span style='font-size:10px;color:#cccccc;'>Alpha testing</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Just do:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <img border="0" src="#" width="100" height="300">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-10">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <span style='font-size:10px;color:#cccccc;'>Alpha testing</span>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ofcourse those are just example Bootstrap classes - you don't have to stick with numbers ;)