# how to expand the table row on click of check box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Onclick of the checkbox I want to expand the table row and and ask for additional information using labels and input tag.But this coming in the straight line and I want this in the new line.
below is the example.

```js
function serverVn(obj) {
      document.getElementById(obj.id + "expand").innerHTML = "<div id='Vn'><label>VNumber:</label><input id='INVn' class='form-control' type='text'/></div>"
    }
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>firstname</th>
      <th>lastname</th>
      <th>dOB</th>
      <th>age</th>
      <th>gender</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id='use0' type='checkbox' name='chkbox' onchange='serverVN(this)' />
      </td>
      <td>john</td>
      <td>john</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td></td>
      <br/>
      <td>
        <div id='use0expand'></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id='use1' type='checkbox' name='chkbox' onchange='serverVN(this)' />
      </td>
      <td>john</td>
      <td>john</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td></td>
      <br/>
      <td>
        <div id='use1expand'></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id='use2' type='checkbox' name='chkbox' onchange='serverVN(this)' />
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td></td>
      <br/>
      <td>
        <div id='use2expand'></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id='use3' type='checkbox' name='chkbox' onchange='serverVN(this)' />
      </td>
      <td>john</td>
      <td>john</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>30</td>
      <br/>
      <td>
        <div id='use3expand'></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id='use4' type='checkbox' name='chkbox' onchange='serverVN(this)' />
      </td>
      <td>john</td>
      <td>john</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>30</td>
      <br/>
      <td>
        <div id='use4expand'></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id='use5' type='checkbox' name='chkbox' onchange='serverVN(this)' />
      </td>
      <td>john</td>
      <td>john</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>30</td>
      <br/>
      <td>
        <div id='use5expand'></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Start by calling the function the same everywhere. JS is case sensitive. then put xxxexpand in a new ROW / cell instead of a cell in the same row

Comment: This is also cause duplicate `ID`'s if the client runs `serverVn();` more than once as `Vn` and `INVn` will be created multiple times. `ID`'s should be unique. You should also be targeting the `ID` of `this` being passed so in your selector you should be using `obj.id+"expend"`

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive language. It means that if you define function as *serverVn*, you can not call it using *serverVN*.

Answer (score 0):

1. JS is case sensitive.
2. Your 
    is invalid HTML
3. use jQuery now you have it
4. Put xxxexpand in a new ROW / cell instead of a cell in the same row
5. Add the obj id to the input too to make unique IDs

I removed the div since you already have a cell you can use

I also remove the new row when unchecked

```js
$(function() {
  $(".sVN").on("click", function() {
    $("#" + this.id + "expand").html(this.checked ? "<label for='INVn" + this.id + "' >VNumber:</label><input id='INVn" + this.id + "' class='form-control' type='text'/>" : "");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>firstname</th>
      <th>lastname</th>
      <th>dOB</th>
      <th>age</th>
      <th>gender</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id='use0' type='checkbox' name='chkbox' class="sVN" />
      </td>
      <td>john</td>
      <td>john</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" id='use0expand'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id='use1' type='checkbox' name='chkbox' class="sVN" />
      </td>
      <td>john</td>
      <td>john</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" id='use1expand'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id='use2' type='checkbox' name='chkbox' class="sVN" />
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" id='use2expand'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id='use3' type='checkbox' name='chkbox' class="sVN" />
      </td>
      <td>john</td>
      <td>john</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" id='use3expand'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id='use4' type='checkbox' name='chkbox' class="sVN" />
      </td>
      <td>john</td>
      <td>john</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" id='use4expand'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id='use5' type='checkbox' name='chkbox' class="sVN" />
      </td>
      <td>john</td>
      <td>john</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" id='use5expand'></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I would also recommend adding `obj.id+"Vn"` and `obj.id+"INVn"` to the `.innerHTML` elements to make those elements have a unique `ID`

Comment: I understood what you did, But there is a line between those two trs. I dont want that line

Comment: What line do you mean? you did not post CSS so I see no lines

Comment: I Created a seperate td because I dont want the line between those two. Or is there any way to create a div after every tr tag

Comment: Actually I gave a bootstrap class=table table-stripped

Comment: Yes - but without CSS. I now added CSS and filled empty cells and fixed missing <TR> tags. Please now explain what you mean by line between... Your BR was invalid HTML

Comment: Is there any way to bring the last <td> to new line?

Comment: Yes with a new row.

Comment: What I want is by clicking on that checkbox the same row should expand. I dont want to create a new row.

Comment: Then don't use a table.

Comment: by giving boostrap class then no need to give CSS seperately

Comment: If you do not include bootstrap then yes you need to include the css

Comment: Ok. Then how i do that?

Comment: Ok, I have updated to include jQuery and bootstrap. Now what.

Comment: I want the label and input field in the same row where the checkbox is clicked but in a new line

Comment: But on a new line? Then you need to use DIVs instead of rows

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32741186/how-to-convert-table-based-layout-with-bootstrap-row-and-col